# Postgres - remove record from parent table without deleting foreign key child table records

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I have an odd use case. A datbase I'm working with has a primary key column that got duplicated for one record - and I'm trying to remove the duplicate, but cannot due to foreign key relations.

Parent table:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | some |
| 1 | other |
| 2 | anoth |

Child table: `child.parent_id = parent.id`

| id | title | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some | 1 |
| 2 | other | 2 |
| 3 | anoth | 2 |

I need to remove the duplicated record from parent table (id=1) but cannot delete it due to foreign key constraints. What is the best path forward here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you managed to create a foreign key that references columns that are not a unique key.

Just drop the foreign key, delete the offending row, and add the foreign key again. Of course, you should only do this when the database is not in use. And probably within a transaction.

You can drop the foreign key with:

```sql
ALTER TABLE child DROP CONSTRAINT the_foreign_key_name;
```

And add it with:

```sql
ALTER TABLE child ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent (id);
```

Comment: Yeah we aren't sure either. This is a third party app built in an old version of Django and it looks like a unique constraint wasn't enforced on the I'd field unfortunately. Not sure how it got duplicated.